# Sides of orthic triangle are parallel to tangent through opposite vertex

Tags: geometry, triangles, tangent-line

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with altitudes $AD$, $BE$, $CF$. Prove that $EF$ is parallel to the tangent to the circumcircle of $ABC$ at $A$. (And similarly $DF$ and $DE$ are parallel to the tangents through $B$ and $C$, respectively.)[image: Diagram]

I'm trying to find a simple direct proof for this, but I can't seem to come up with one.

Comment: Just check that the tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $A$ intersects $AB$ at the same angle as the line $EF$. (The former angle is obtained from the chordal-angle theorem; the latter from the inscribed quadrilateral $AEHF$, where $H$ is the orthocenter. Google "antiparallels" for more about this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall use directed angles modulo $180^{\circ}$. (See [Evan Chen, *How to Use Directed Angles*, 31 May 2015](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Directed-Angles/Directed-Angles.pdf) or, if you read German, [my *Orientierte Winkel modulo 180° und eine Lösung der WURZEL -Aufgabe Kappa 22 von Wilfried Haag*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/Dreigeom/OrWinkel.zip), for an introduction to this type of angles.)

Let $x$ be the tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $A$. Thus, $\measuredangle \left(AC, x\right) = \measuredangle CBA$ (by the well-known theorem stating that a tangent-chord angle equals the corresponding chordal angle).

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$. The points $E$ and $F$ lie on the circle with diameter $AH$ (since both angles $\measuredangle AEH$ and $\measuredangle AFH$ are $90^{\circ}$). Thus, the points $A$, $E$, $F$ and $H$ lie on one circle. Hence, the chordal angle theorem yields
\begin{align}
\measuredangle AEF
& = \measuredangle AHF = \measuredangle \left(AH, HC\right)
= \underbrace{\measuredangle \left(AH, BC\right)}_{=90^\circ \text{ (since $AH \perp BC$)}}
+ \underbrace{\measuredangle \left(BC, AB\right)}_{=\measuredangle CBA}
+ \underbrace{\measuredangle \left(AB, HC\right)}_{=90^\circ \text{ (since $HC \perp AB$)}} \\
&= 90^\circ + \measuredangle CBA + 90^\circ = \underbrace{180^\circ}_{=0^\circ} + \measuredangle CBA = \measuredangle CBA .
\end{align}
Hence, $\measuredangle \left(AC, EF\right) = \measuredangle AEF = \measuredangle CBA = \measuredangle \left(AC, x\right)$, so that $EF \parallel x$, qed. $\blacksquare$

In the language of triangle geometry, lines parallel to $x$ and $EF$ are said to be *antiparallel* to $BC$ with respect to $\triangle ABC$.